# How to call the action method from angular service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call the mvc controller in angular service.js file.

```
     public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            using (EmployeeEntities datacontext = new EmployeeEntities())
            {
                var employeelist = datacontext.Employees.ToList();
                return Json(employeelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

}
}

Angular controller:

```
app.controller("mycontroller", function ($scope, myservice) {
debugger;
GetAllEmployee();
$scope.divEmployee = false;

function GetAllEmployee() {
    debugger;

    var getData = myservice.getAllEmployees();
    getData.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees = emp.data;
    }),
    function(){
        alert('Error in getting data');
    }
}
```

});
Angular service.js

```
pp.service("myservice", ["$http", function ($http) {
this.getAllEmployees = function () {
    debugger;
    var response = $http({
        url: "/Home/GetAll",
        method: "GET",

        datatype:'JSON'
    })
        return response;
    });
```

So when i trying run call the Url, the "Home/GetAll" is not found error is coming.
So how to call the url in service.

Comment: Does calling the method through the browser work?

Comment: No, i'm calling through chrome.

Comment: If you can't call it directly without using Ajax, then that's your problem, not how you're calling it.